# BLE Supported Android Phones

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to know if we can detect android phones as well with BLE Scan. I am trying to develop an android app which can scan nearby Bluetooth Android devices.

I checked both android devices are compatible with BLE with this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myan.michaelyanyoga.bluetoothchecker

Note: I am using this code to develop my scanner app: https://github.com/kaviles/BLE_Tutorials. I am able to see my laptop Bluetooth on this list but not other android phones(which supports BLE).

Answer (score 1):

To detect Android phones using BLE, the other device needs to:-

1. Have Bluetooth turned on.
2. Be advertising

Unfortunately, most devices are not doing this by default, which means you may not be able to use BLE for your intended purposes. You can test this by doing the following:-

1. Download the [nRF Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=en) Android app.
2. Go to ADVERTISER from the top menu.
3. Toggle the "Test" advertiser.

After this you should begin to see your Android device via Bluetooth.

I hope this helps.